# bayes net open source

Tags: statistics, bayesian, prediction, bayesian-networks, markov-chains

Can anyone recommend a good opensource or free bayes net software program?

I have been using baysealab with a class, but my account will expire and I'd like to continue building and using bns.

Comment: Consider updating with what you are looking or: a library? a DSL? an end-user program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to matlab: 
[BNT](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/) is great

If you prefer python:
[NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) or [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/)

Or for Java: 
[Weka API](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index_documentation.html)

Weka does not have the best documented API, but is quite rich in what algorithms are available.

Hope this helps.